# Как максимально уменьшить размер .exe файла? pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Подскажите, как можно минимизировать размер .exe файла, сделанного с помощью pyinstaller.
Я использую в своем коде только встроенные библиотеки, никаких внешних импортов.
В таком случае, вес .exe получается 6.5мб.

Я бы хотел узнать, есть ли еще какие-нибудь трюки, с помощью которых можно уменьшить размер выходящего .exe файла.
Я хотел-бы услышать даже самые безумные, вроде пересборки интерпретатора из исходников, с удалением неиспользуемых модулей, если такие есть...

Если вы имели такой опыт, или может видели ссылку, где кто-нибудь уже таким занимался.
Буду признателен за ваш ответ.

Comment: Ну да, стандартный чистый python примерно столько и весит, очень вряд ли получится сделать меньше

Comment: Пересборка это интересно, но если вам так нужна экономия, то наверное будет лучше просто другой язык программирования выбрать, компилируемый какой-нибудь

Comment: `pklite.exe my_cool.exe` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression#PKLITE

Comment: Cython?8 символов нужно...

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответы. Знаю, что это нормальный вес для интерпретатора питона. И так-же знаю, что для экономии лучше на компилируемых языках.
И про упаковщики тоже наслышан.
Спрашиваю непосредственно про максимальное сжатия методами питона.
У меня спортивный интерес.

Comment: Интересует, можно ли вырезать из интерпретатора, не используемые стандартные библиотеки, такие как tkinter итд